# Why does request by hostname return 1 site, but request by ip returns another

Tags: http, curl, dns, hostname

I've got an issue trying to redirect (via a proxy) in which going to a site through some http queries gives me 1 result, but other http query which should look identical give me another. The site is hosted on namecheap, so I don't have direct control over what it serves (though obviously we decided what content was up there).

One way to repro it, on my local machine using curl is:

- goes to the correct minimal site: `curl ftl.ltd -L`
- goes to some old prototype by the original owner: `curl 198.187.29.248 -L`

Where: `nslookup ftl.ltd` outputs `198.187.29.248`

I have verified the headers in the requests are identical, that 198.187.29.248 is the address resolved by ftl.ltd, and even tried duplicating the headers a browser sends. As far as I can tell there is absolutely no different between my request by ip, and request by hostname.

Clearly I've misunderstood something related to how these requests are resolved, and haven't managed to find the right thing to search for to answer the question. Does anybody with expertise in this have an idea as to how this can happen?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: "I have verified the headers in the requests are identical" the `host` field is probably different.

Comment: No using 2 identical host values still makes no difference. I tried both forcing the 'host' was ftl.ltd in both requests, and forcing it to be '198.187.29.248'. Both yielded exactly the same result.

Comment: This, for example, when used for the headers yields the same result in both cases: 
- 'host:ftl.ltd
- user-agent:curl/7.47.0
- accept:*/*

Answer (score 0):

If you already had checked the headers on the request, check that the DNS records are only returning the desired IP, you could use `dig` for this:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 ftl.ltd +trace
```

Also check for IPv6 just in case:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 AAAA ftl.ltd +trace
```

Here `dig` will use the DNS servers from Google and should return something like this at the end:

```
ftl.ltd    1200     IN      A       198.187.29.248
```

The idea of this is to check that you are getting always the same values and to discard that probably you are pointing to old records in case you just moved your domain from one host to another and DNS are been replicated.

Regarding doing the requests via IP or hostname, and getting different results for each, is because the server(s) may be configured to support virtual hosts.

> The technique for hosting more than one domain/subdomain on a single IP address/host is called virtual hosts.

This means that response for a request like (using www.ftl.ltd):

```
curl -v -L -H 'Host: www.ftl.ltd' 198.187.29.248
```

Could be different from this requests (using only ftl.ltd):

```
curl -v -L -H 'Host: ftl.ltd' 198.187.29.248
```

The reasons for this is because it could be one virtual host for  `www.ftl.ltd` another for `ftl.ltd` or in many casese it could be the same vhost for both, normally a wildcard is used: `*.ftl.ltd`

When doing the request directly by IP:

```
curl -v -L 198.187.29.248
```

It will return the defined `default_server` but in shared environments is something you normally don't control which seems to be your case, therefore you are bound to only use hostnames.

Comment: Hi @nbari, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm fairly certain neither of those is the issue. the dig turns up fine results, and as I say, I've verified the issue exists even if I force a 'host' header in the direct ip request. i.e. your last 3 examples all return the erroneous site. I think next step will be to load up wireshark to check _exactly_ what is getting sent, but I'm still baffled!

Comment: probably there is no `vhost` for your site or is not configured

Comment: Wow - more research and it turns out you were right. I've been using 'ARC' to generate my requests, but it seems somewhere between clicking Send in 'ARC' (having specified a Host), and it leaving my machine, the Host is getting replaced with the IP address. Using your curl approach from a linux box gives the correct result, so I'm guessing the issue is either in 'ARC', or something installed in windows.